# MS Excel - How can I create a pivot table for 3 dimensional data with no numerical values employing OR logic

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I am not sure if this type of question was posted here before because I myself am not sure how to ask it. So here goes, I have a massive three-dimensional dataset that looks somewhat like the table below, but with 10 "Offers" and around 40000 "Persons" rows with several hundreds of "Companies".

| Person | Company | Offer 1 | Offer 2 | Offer 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Person 1 | Company 1 | Rejected | Accepted | On hold |
| Person 2 | Company 1 | Accepted | Rejected | Accepted |
| Person 3 | Company 1 | On hold | On hold | Rejected |
| Person 4 | Company 2 | Accepted | Rejected | Accepted |
| Person 5 | Company 2 | Accepted | Rejected | Rejected |
| Person 6 | Company 2 | On hold | Rejected | On hold |
| Person 7 | Company 3 | Rejected | Accepted | Rejected |
| Person 8 | Company 3 | Accepted | Accepted | Accepted |
| Person 9 | Company 4 | On hold | Accepted | Accepted |
| Person 10 | Company 5 | Rejected | On hold | Accepted |
| Person 11 | Company 5 | Accepted | Rejected | On hold |
| Person 12 | Company 5 | Accepted | Rejected | On hold |

What I need is a (Pivot) table that shows how many people from every company has Accepted the offer. How so much ever I try, what I get is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TNui.png) here, that is, the table only shows the person that has accepted ALL three offers. Is there any way for the Pivot table columns to show OR instead of AND? My ideal solution would be this table [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nn0zq.png). Is this possible? Is this because there are no numerical data in the table?

P.S: I understand I can use COUNTIF but I would also need the table to be dynamic (knowing who actually accepted the offer by clicking on the number, or add another row below each company to know who the people are, etc.
P.P.S: Yes, I've tried using "Distinct Count" and I have filtered the Offers by "Accepted" within the Pivottable options dialog.

Hope you super users can help me out here? I will be much obliged!
TIA!

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the following information is helful to you.

- Select your table and add it to PowerPivot.
- Create 3 measures for "Offer1", "Offer2" and "Offer3".

  Offer1:=CALCULATE(COUNT(Table1[Offer 1]),FILTER(Table1,Table1[Offer 1]="Accepted"))

  [image]

  Offer2:=CALCULATE(COUNT(Table1[Offer 2]),FILTER(Table1,Table1[Offer 2]="Accepted"))

  Offer3:=CALCULATE(COUNT(Table1[Offer 3]),FILTER(Table1,Table1[Offer 3]="Accepted"))
- Then create a pivot table. You can select the tabe, go to `Design > Layout > Subtotals > Show all subtotals at top of group`.

  [image]

  Please note, you need some settings if the layout of pivot table does not meet you needs, please go to `Design > Layout > Report Layout`, change its layout.

Comment: Wow thank you so much Emily! This worked and how! I feels stupid for not knowing about PowerPivot until now. Thank you again!